# I accidentally hid my right "toolbar"? in Blender and don't know how to get it back

Tags: modeling, rendering, modifiers, shortcut

I was just working on my first ever Blender project when I pressed a key or a button by accident and my "toolbar" (Idk what to call it) just disappeared and I don't know how to get it back... I NEED MY MODIFIER!![image: My right "toolbar" being gone.]

Comment: Type the N key when you are hovering in the 3D area.  It will toggle visibility of that bar, which is called the 'sidebar' in the Blender documents.

Comment: That wont' get the outliner and modifier panels back as you can see from the position of the gizmos. I suspect the 3D window is now maximised, so press CTRL-SPACE with the cursor in the 3D view.

Comment: @JohnEason Could be but shouldn't there be a "Back to Previous" button in the top bar in that case?

Comment: @MartyFouts Yes that's true. It's a bit difficult to see from the supplied image as it's so small, but just tapping the 'N' key wouldn't bring the modifier and outliner panels back. I thought when I first looked at it that the edge of the 3D window might have been dragged right to the edge of Blender's main window, but if you do that it stops before the icons down the side of the properties panel disappear, so I'm still scratching my head here! I do wish that all the questioners would add a comment letting us know whether the problem is sorted, but often you don't even get any reply. :^(

Comment: It just looks like you dragged the ui til the outliner and properties editor areas got closed. Nothing wrong here, that's how you manage areas anyways. And it's easy to get bag. On each area corner, there's a place where you cursor change. Click and drag towards the inside of the area to split it into two areas. Then assign the newly created area to any editor you like: outliner or properties. And repeat anywhere hou want and as many times as you want to get any other editor.

Comment: @L0Lock TYSM BRO that was so helpful!